# How to run Mapr?

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, vmware, mapr

I am trying to run mapr sandbox on a windows pc and with 8gb ram. But when I am trying to import the ovf its always saying ovf is corrupt while I have used multiple sources the ovf that is running on the other machine is not running in my one.I have tried to play with the configuration as well I also tried to extract and run the ovf as a vmdk but than there will be no config setup done for so that doesn't works as well. Now I have tried that on vmplayer it got install and said that the ovf format is unsupproted and when you try again it will not see the ovf file specification concern so it imported the file successfully but now its says that the vmx file is incompatible. I cannot find any way out?

Comment: Can you try with Virtual Box? (and I will check with other users if they have the same issue)

Comment: I tried with both vmware and virtual box it was not working now I am running it on ubuntu might be a windows 7 issue

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for install it on Ubuntu 14.04 (being virtual machines the final destination, shouldn't be mayor problems):

On VirtualBox

- Don't use the ovf file.
- Create virtual machine (Machine -> New...)
- On operating system, choose red hat 64 bits
- On memory, you should asing 8 GB for the VM (or less, if you have an old computer like me :D)
- Don't add virtual drives, you can't add both drives. Use the option "Do not add a Virtual Hard Drive"
- After creation of the VM

  - Add both disks to the virtual machine, from settings
  - Configure the network of the machine as following

    - Attached to "Bridget Adapter"
    - Name: Eht0
    - Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop
    - Promiscuos mode: Deny
    - Cable Connected: yes

After this small steps, you should be capable of doing right click -> start, and start using MapR. Basically, we import the machine in a very complicated way, because the ovf file that is supposed to use for importing doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue on my Windows & machine. Here is what I did:

1. Again downloaded MapR sandbox for VMWare for windows.
2. Uninstalled previous version of VMWare which was giving this issue and downloaded VMWare Workstation Player for Windows 64 bit.

This time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I had the chance to experiment with MapR recently-

**MapR needs 6GB RAM**

at least for the Virtual Box
(or the virtual machine you are using on windows)
if you don't grant the MapR these 6gb it is just not starting with some strange error saying nothing about that issue. You have 8gb ram on your windows machine so I recommend you to spend at least 6.2gb ram for the process.

*p.s. Later I had other problems with the mapper as you can see with no support. (previous I found 1 more bug that they say will be fixed in MapR 6)
I am currently using MapR 5.2*